# peerJS audiocall only works locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, webrtc, peerjs

I don't know what to do at this point as docs are pretty clear about this and it doesnt work.
Here's what I'm doing to set up an audio call using peer js and their cloud server for which I got an API key:

--note that I'm not happy putting a chunk of code here, but here it is.
the commented-out part is an attempt to follow an official documentation.
Also I'm not getting unsecure origin errors. There's a live demo @ https://thealmightyone.github.io/AMAclient

TO TEST:

1. register and login 2 players
2. right click one
3. choose talk to
4. accept call in the right click corner
5. you can clearly see the logs in the console.

   function peerJsTools() {
       var allAudioCalls = {};
       var playerPeer = new Peer({key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9'}); // MOVE PEERJS API KEY TO NETWORK SETTINGS

   ```
   var playerPeerId;
   this.getPeerId = function() {
       return playerPeerId;
   };
   navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
   playerPeer.on('open', function(id) {
       console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
       playerPeerId = id;
   });

   playerPeer.on('call', function(call) {
       console.log('incoming call detected')
       navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
       navigator.getUserMedia({
           video: false,
           audio: true
       }, function(stream) {
           call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
           call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
               console.log('PEERJS: incoming audio stream', remoteStream);
               // WEBAUDIO API BELOW - DOESN'T WORK IN CHROME?
               // var audioContext = new AudioContext();
               // var audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(remoteStream);
               // audioStream.connect(audioContext.destination);
                 var audio = $('<audio autoplay />').appendTo('body');
                 audio[0].src = (URL || webkitURL || mozURL).createObjectURL(remoteStream);
           });
       }, function(err) {
           console.log('Failed to get local stream', err);
       });
   });

   this.initiatePeerAudioCall = function(id, peerId) {
       navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
       navigator.getUserMedia({
               video: false,
               audio: true
           }, function(stream) {
               var call = playerPeer.call(peerId, stream);

               console.log('PEERJS: calling', peerId, 'with', stream);

               allAudioCalls[id] = call;
               call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
                   console.log('PEERJS: got an answer back');
                   // var audioContext = new AudioContext();
                   // var audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(remoteStream);
                   // audioStream.connect(audioContext.destination);
                     var audio = $('<audio autoplay />').appendTo('body');
                     audio[0].src = (URL || webkitURL || mozURL).createObjectURL(remoteStream);
               });
           }, function(err) {
               console.log('Failed to get local stream', err);
           }
       );
   };

   this.endActiveCall = function(id) {
       if(allAudioCalls[id]){
           console.log('ending active call');
           allAudioCalls[id].close();
       }
       else{
           console.log('stopping call attempt');
       }
   };
   ```

   }

What's going on here? I thought I'm receiving remote streams and creating audio elements correctly.

Comment: are there STUN or TURN servers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they provide both,  how do I check that?

Comment: check connexion establishment, there must be server IP and port for that in the code